# Why does the EntityFramework update the master entity in a master-detail relationship if a detail entity is modified?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a very simple master-detail structure in database which is accessed via Entity Framework using the following model:

[image: Entity Framework model]

Master entity modifications are mapped via Insert/Update/Delete stored procedures.

A Detail entity is loaded and edited and it's Master entity is loaded into the context as well but that is not modified. When changes are saved both Detail and Master entities are updated even though the Master entity was not changed at all (Detail entity => parameterized update statement; Master entity => update stored procedure call).

```
using (var context = new PlayGroundEntities())
{
    var master = context.Masters.First(m => m.MasterId == MasterAId);
    var detail = context.Details.First(d => d.DetailId == MasterADetail1Id);
    detail.DetailValue = "Detail Value";
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is very strange for me and I would like to get rid of the Master entity update sp call if the Master entity is not modified.
If Master entity updates are not mapped via stored procedures (normal ef stuff, simple parameterized insert/update/delete sql statements are generated) this strange behavior does not occur.

This is just a very simple example. In the real project I have a complex model where the same problem occurs and I would like really much to get rid of that. Unfortunately I really have to use the stored procedure mappings and the loading of the "Master" entity is also important.

Did anybody experience something like this or managed to get rid of it somehow?
I am using Entity Framework 4.0 released with .NET Framweork 4.0.

Thank You in advance for Your help!

Comment: "Unfortunately I really have to use the stored procedure mappings" - You might save yourself some hastle if you don't.  I haven't really found a scenario where you gain anything by having sprocs for CUD, other than the fact that you restrict setwise operations (which basically kills some performance optimizations).

Comment: Have you tried removing the query on `Masters` entirely?  Does it update if you remove it?

Comment: In the real project insert/update/delete stored procedures are needed as they are performing things which cannot be done otherwise (master is hierarchical, hierarchyid has to be created on insert, things have to be updated in the subtree on update, etc.). I feel like EF has some bug when stored procedures are used, I would like to have some workaround for that.

Comment: You are right, if 'Masters' query is removed then the Master entity is not updated. But this kind of a code is present quite many places and is actually needed, so it would not be nice to change it everywhere. If something is not changed then it should not be saved, it does not matter if sp-s or normal inserts/updates/deletes are used for saving that entity.

Comment: I just noticed your diagram doesn't match your code.  Your diagram shows the link being stored in `Detail`, whereas your code shows the link stored in `Master`.  Either way I wouldn't expect a query to call an update sproc - that does sound like a bug, unless there is somehow something missing from the description.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham The diagram is in sync with the code. 'MasterADetail1Id' is just a constant with a Detail entity key, which belogns to a Master entity with 'MasterAId' key. Detail entities have a foreign key pointing to a Master entity.

Comment: @Merlyn Otherwise I totally agree with you that this seems like a bug in EF. If the Master entity is not mapped with i/u/d stored procedures in the model the same code does not trigger an update sql statement for the Master entity which was loaded by the query. This is the correct behavior. On the other hand if i/u/d stored procedures are mapped the same example code executes the update stored procedure (on context.SaveChanges();) which is totally wrong in my opinion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5057/discussion-between-zoltan-and-merlyn-morgan-graham)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but maybe this will help, so try detach master in order to get rid of Master entity update sp:

```
context.Detach(master);
```

Comment: You are right, if the loaded master entity is detached then it is not updated. But this kind of code is present quite many places and the master entity is actually needed.

Comment: @Zoltan: By doing detach, master still hold a value but the update will not accour. There is no magic trick that will apply the change you want in all over your code. I think that your best option is to do the master select query after the SaveChanges() or simply doing detach. Other way will be somehow to disable attaching in your context but that will also prevent from detail to be updated.